# css3: two transitions with different timing functions (css3)

Tags: css, transform, scale, css-transitions

I want to use a transform for both `scale` and `translateX`, but each with a different timing function. Currently I have it working with absolute positioning instead of `translateX`, as follows:

```
transition: transform 500ms cubic-bezier(0.390, -0.600, 1.000, -0.600), 
            left 500ms cubic-bezier(0.270, 0.875, 0.575, 0.870);
```

.

```
left: -50px ;
transform: scale(2,2) ;
```

How would you rewrite this to achieve the same, but use `translateX` instead of `left` ?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

In this case, I would probably use a wrapper and transition one of the two transforms for the wrapper and the other one for the element itself.

## [*demo*](http://codepen.io/thebabydino/pen/wbImJ)

HTML:

```
<div class='wrap'>
  <div class='el'></div>
</div>
```

Relevant CSS:

```
.wrap {
  transition: transform .5s cubic-bezier(.39, -.6, 1, -.6);
}
.el {
  transition: transform .5s cubic-bezier(.27, .875, .575, .87);
}
.wrap:hover { transform: scale(2,2); }
.wrap:hover .el { transform: translateX(-50px); }
```

Not sure it's a better idea than simulating a `translateX` by using `left`.

Another idea would be not to use a `transition`, but an `animation` and set the keyframes such that to obtain the desired effect.