# CSS transition rotate() and not translate()

Tags: css, css-transitions, css-transforms

I am using both `rotate()` and `translate()` properties on an element. I have very specific transition requirements where I need to transition the `rotate()` property of an element and not the `translate()` property. Is there a way to declare a `transition` on the `rotate()` property without declaring it on the `translate()` property. This has so far proven tricky with CSS conflating the two properties under the `transform` property.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: No, that is not possible, _because_ you are dealing with only one single CSS property here. But what is the problem with just keeping the `translate` part of it as-is? If you transition from `rotate(foo) translate(baz)` to `rotate(bar) translate(baz)`, that should give you the desired result, no?

Answer (score 1):

I don't think you can do what you want, but check out this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22082684/multiple-simultaneous-css3-transform-transitions-at-varied-speeds), the approach might interest you, wrap your element and apply one transform to the wrapper and another to the actual element, that way you can transition the transform you want. I hope it helps!

Answer (score 1):

One way to do this would be to use one single property which can represent both translation and rotation. 
The matrix property under 2D transforms might just help you out here.

```
rotate(45deg) translate(24px,25px);
```

can be converted to

```
matrix(0.707107, 0.707107, -0.707107, 0.707107, -0.707108, 34.6482);
```

This conversion can be achieved using matrix resolutions: [The Matrix Resolutions](https://meyerweb.com/eric/tools/matrix/)
Hope this helps out.

Comment: Sorry but that won't help for transitionning only one of rotate or translate. If we cannot transition these funcs separately it is actually because the one value that is used is the matrix() func... As soon as it's been parsed, UA will convert it to the matrix equivalent, and the computed value of transform is always either "none" or "matrix(a,b,c,d,e,f)".