# How to transition one property in 0s and all the rest in 1.5s

Tags: css, css-transitions

I'm trying to transition outline immediately, but all other properties slowly. How can I do that?

```css
div {
  background: red;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  transition: outline 0s, all 1.5s;
}

div:hover {
  outline: 4px dotted grey;
  width: 200px;
  background: blue;
}
```

```html
<div>
</div>
```

Comment: Maybe this would help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22082684/multiple-simultaneous-css3-transform-transitions-at-varied-speeds

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make the `outline` the last one in the list

```css
div {
  background: red;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  transition: all 1.5s, outline 0s;
}

div:hover {
  outline: 4px dotted grey;
  width: 200px;
  background: blue;
}
```

```html
<div>
</div>
```

> If a **property is specified multiple times** in the value of `transition-property` (either on its own, via a shorthand that contains it, **or via the all value**), then the transition that starts uses the duration, delay, and timing function at the index corresponding to **the last item in the value of transition-property** that calls for animating that property. <sup>[ref](https://drafts.csswg.org/css-transitions/#transition-property-property)</sup>

Answer (score 2):

```css
div {
  background: red;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  transition: outline 0s, width 1.5s, background 1.5s;
}

div:hover {
  outline: 4px dotted grey;
  width: 200px;
  background: blue;
}
```

```html
<div>
</div>
```

Comment: There's no "rest of the properties" property? I have to name each of them?

Comment: You should avoid 'all' for performance reasons, because the value makes the browser  loop through all properties.